# Error parsing XML: unbound prefix (android Manifest)

Tags: java, android, xml

Help me please, i am beginner
I'm creating an app that displays a website, but, I'm having this problem
My code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.aide.trainer.myapp"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   
   <uses-sdk 
       android:minSdkVersion="8" 
       android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

   <application
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name" >
       
       <activity
           android:label="@string/app_name"            
           Android:theme="@style/Theme."...
           android:name=".MainActivity">           
           <intent-filter >
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>            
       </activity>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

Help me please,I don't know why this is happening

Comment: XML is case-sensitive, so `Android` is not the same as `android` (see the `Android:theme="@style/Theme."...` line).

Comment: @Andreas: I thought [I just said that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62490432/290085)  ;-)

Comment: @kjhughes Yeah, but this is a useless question to keep around, since it's caused by a **typo**, so I voted to close for that reason, and I think the question should be deleted, hence it should not be answered, since an answer with an up-vote prevents deletion by OP.

Comment: @Andreas: I know the typo close concept, and you might be sharper than I, but with even with nearly three decades of markup experience, I didn't spot his problem immediately.  Future readers might not benefit from this instance but might from the concept that a namespace prefix's use has to match its declaration's case.  Anyway, that's why I didn't VTC.

Comment: I agree with @kjhughes - error messages directly indicative of a typo (like this) are generally useful to have questions explaining.  Random errors caused by a typo elsewhere are not.

Comment: @RyanM: Thanks, and please feel free to further express your approval via an upvote on the answer to help ensure it survives.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
       Android:theme="@style/Theme."...
       ^
```

to

```
       android:theme="@style/Theme."
       ^
```

because XML is case-sensitive.

Comment: I had assumed that those `...`  were meta comments, but to be clear, I've removed them from the recommended line update.  Obviously one cannot have `...` in an element's attribute list like that.